# Writing a custom unbounded sink for Dataflow v2.1

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using the mvn dependency [google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) version 2.1.0 and I'm trying to add a custom Sink for my pipeline.

In the pipeline, I'm retrieving [Pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) messages and am eventually transforming these to a PCollection of Strings.

This is a simplified version of the pipeline I've set up:

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readMessages())
     .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1))))

//transformations

.apply(//Write to custom sink)
```

The reason I need a custom Sink is because someone else on the team has already written the code to write out this data to BigQuery and provided a REST API for this. So, my Sink would be calling this REST API with the relevant data. I'm not keen on using BigQueryIO since that would involve duplicating parts of the code that was already written.

The problem is that I can not find any documentation on the [Apache Beam website](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/) about writing custom Sinks using the Java SDK, so if someone could give me a nod in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

I've also considered just using a ParDo to send the data to the REST API, but then I technically would not have a Sink anymore and I wouldn't be doing it the "Dataflow way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unbounded sinks, there is no sink specific API in Beam. All the IO transforms essentially implement a ParDo. There are a few techniques to provide specific guarantees (e.g. using a `GroupByKey` to provide a checkpoint barrier in Dataflow) it depends on your interaction with external system (REST API in this case). Looks like writing a `ParDo` is the way to go in your case.